# Using webpack to simply transpile and concat files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So i am trying to figure out how to use webpack to replace our current brunch build process. Basically we have an angular 1 app which doesnt utilise requires or imports at all and I want to have webpack just concat+transpile the files (there are both coffee and sass files and ill need to be able to watch and create source maps using the usual settings). This angular app is sitting inside another application which is using webpack extensively.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this? Is this even possible without the app using any form of javascript modules?

Here is my current config:

```
var webpack  = require( "webpack" );
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");
var glob = require("glob");

const exportConfig = {
   entry: {
        app: glob.sync('./front-end/applications/core/app/**/*.coffee'),
        vendor: ['angular']
    },    
    output: {
        filename: "app.bundle.js",
        path: path.join( __dirname, "../www_root/build" ),
    },
    debug: true,  
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.coffee$/, 
                loader: "coffee-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|es6)/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|www_root\/bower)/,
                loader: "babel",
            },                        
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js"),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", {
            allChunks: true
        }),     
    ]  
}

module.exports = exportConfig
```

I basically just get an output file with an error for each of the files obviously:

```
(function webpackMissingModule() { throw new Error("Cannot find module \"./front-end/applications/core/app/components/app/module.coffee\""); }());
```

Thanks!